# Linking a native component using react-native-create-app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I use react-native-create-app cli and i want to link a native component like **react-native link** without eject the app. 
I have a warning like :

> Warning: Native component for "NMRangeSlider" does not exist

Comment: Did you checked the component been present in your application(inside node_modules) ? It could happen that the dependency/component is there in your package.json files, but not installed in your node modules.

Comment: i have installed it in my node_modules. I see it

Comment: Why you wanted to link the component. Can't you just import it and use the same ?

Comment: i do it but it's not work. it's necessary that i link the component. i do it with eject the app and i apply react-native link. When i use react-native-create-app, the doesn't work